# Connecting to a service from a Gitlab CI job

Tags: docker, tomcat, gitlab-ci

I am attempting to run e2e tests in the gitlab ci that use a React frontend, Java Spring backend and PostgreSQL.

The relevant pieces of the `.gitlab-ci` -config are as follows:

```
variables:
  IMAGE_NAME: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1

docker-backend-build:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - docker:dind
  stage: package
  dependencies:
    - backend-build
  script:
  - docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/repo-name .
  - docker tag registry.gitlab.com/repo-name $IMAGE_NAME
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
  - docker push $IMAGE_NAME

end-to-end-test:
  stage: integration-test
  image: node:latest
  services:
    - name: postgres:9.6
    - name: $IMAGE_NAME
      alias: backend
  variables:
    DB_USERNAME: postgres
    DB_PASSWORD: postgres
    JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING: 'jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/database?stringtype=unspecified'
  dependencies:
    - frontend-build
  script:
    - cd frontend
    - yarn start:ci & ./node_modules/wait-on/bin/wait-on http://backend:9070/api/health http://localhost:3000
    - yarn run cy:run
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - frontend/cypress/videos/*.mp4
      - frontend/cypress/screenshots/**/*.png
    expire_in: 1 day
```

The Dockerfile for the backend is as follows:

```
FROM tomcat:latest
ADD backend/target/server.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
RUN sed -i 's/port="8080"/port="9070"/' /usr/local/tomcat/conf/server.xml
EXPOSE 9070
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

The `server.war` is created on an earlier stage in the CI-pipeline.

The `server.war` is set to listen to port 9070, and the Dockerfile succesfully changes the Tomcat port to 9070 as well. The Tomcat instance is able to connect to the postgres instance via `postgres:5432` because of the `FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD` -flag, but for some reason this script hangs on the `wait-on http://backend:9070/api/health` command forever. It can not connect to backend:9070 even though the server is up and running. (and the health-endpoint exists). The server doesn't receive any indication that it is trying to be connected to.

What could I be doing wrong? I also tried to connect to `http://localhost:9070/api/health` but that didn't work either.

Comment: I am having a similar problem, which I had previously fixed by creating a Dockerfile for my frontend app that just exposes the port I need open. I.E. `FROM node:latest EXPOSE 3000`. However, this has become an issue again after migrating from a self-hosted GitLab to gitlab.com.

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/outlandish/node-expose

Comment: Does your backend process listen on `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`? Because I think it needs to listen on `0.0.0.0` to accept external connections.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was simply changing the Dockerfile as follows:

```
- ADD backend/target/server.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
+ ADD backend/target/server.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
```

because without that, the server was actually listening in `http://backend:9070/api/health/server`. Silly me.